# Git Extensions guide?

Tags: git, git-extensions

Is there a quick-start guide to using Git Extensions for basic tasks such as checkout, checkin, undo-checkout, etc, especially for users coming from the Microsoft world?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure what quick-start means, but the [Git Extensions manual](http://gitextensions.googlecode.com/files/Git%20Extensions%20-%20User%20Manual.pdf) is very user friendly. If you're wondering how to check out branches, see chapter 6, page 18.

Answer (score 3):

Also check the video's on youtube, they show the basic flow:

1. Clone - Git Extensions - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TlZXSkJGKF8
2. Commit changes - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B8uvje6X7lo
3. Push changes - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JByfXdbVAiE
4. Pull changes - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9g8gXPsi5Ko
5. Handle merge conflicts - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kmc39RvuGM8

Answer (score 2):

Some of my readers also asked for a comprehensive guide on Git for Windows so I put together a post that walks you through installing Git Extensions.

http://www.codetunnel.com/installing-git-on-windows

Comment: @TimH fixed it for ya.